# Return variable from a reader.onload event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fileapi

I am reading an array via `JavaScript` and saving the size of that array in a reader.onload event. I think that the `reader.onload` function is called when the file has finished uploading. 
    `event.target.result` stores that array. I would like that array saved as a variable to be used in other functions but, I tried initializing an empty array and using the

```
slice
```

function but, it didn't work. The console returns an undefined value.

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Home Page </title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
    <output id="list"></output>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
      function handleFileSelect(evt) { 
        // grab the file that was uploaded which is type File. 
        // evt is the event that was triggered
        // evt.target returns the element that triggered the event 
        // evt.target.files[0] returns the file that was uploaded, type File
        var file = evt.target.files[0]; 

        var myArray = [];
        // instantiate a FileReader object to read/save the file that was uploaded
        var reader = new FileReader();
          // when the load event is fired (the file has finished uploading) this function is called
        reader.onload = function(event) {
          // the result attribute contains an ArrayBuffer representing the file's data. 
          var arrayBuffer = event.target.result;
          myArray = arrayBuffer.slice(0);
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arrayBuffer.byteLength;
        }

        // read the file and save as an array. Once the read is finished loadend is triggered
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        console.log(myArray.byteLength);
      }

      //console.log(myArray.byteLength);
      document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`onload` happens asynchronously. So whatever logic depends on `myArray` needs to happen within that `onload` function.

```
    reader.onload = function(event) {
      var arrayBuffer = event.target.result;
      var myArray = arrayBuffer.slice(0);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arrayBuffer.byteLength;

      // this needs to happen here
      console.log(myArray.byteLength);
    }

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

This is very, very similar to the often asked question (regarding AJAX/async callbacks) [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

By the way, this is asynchronous because we don't want to block the entire user interface while waiting for the potentially long operation of reading a file. That's why we're using an `onload` handler here.

Comment: does that mean I can't use myArray outside of that function? I would like to echo the contents of it onto the screen and just have that string available to use to create thinks and such.

Comment: @Crt, correct. All that logic needs to happen inside of the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code .. i think you will understand what was your mistake

```html
<body>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
    <output id="list"></output>

    <p id="demo"></p>
    <p id="log"></p>

    <script>
      function onReadFinish(result){
      console.log("Read Finished: "  + result.byteLength);
         document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = "Read Finished: "  + result.byteLength;
      }
      function handleFileSelect(evt) { 
        // grab the file that was uploaded which is type File. 
        // evt is the event that was triggered
        // evt.target returns the element that triggered the event 
        // evt.target.files[0] returns the file that was uploaded, type File
        var file = evt.target.files[0]; 

        var myArray = [];
        // instantiate a FileReader object to read/save the file that was uploaded
        var reader = new FileReader();
          // when the load event is fired (the file has finished uploading) this function is called
        reader.onload = function(event) {
          // the result attribute contains an ArrayBuffer representing the file's data. 
          var arrayBuffer = event.target.result;
          myArray = arrayBuffer.slice(0);
          onReadFinish(myArray);
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arrayBuffer.byteLength;
        }

        // read the file and save as an array. Once the read is finished loadend is triggered
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        
      }

      //console.log(myArray.byteLength);
      document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: @SaItukwhen i run that code, nothing pops up in the console.

Comment: yes, the size of the arrayBuffer is shown but, nothing else

Comment: That worked! But, my question is how can I save that array to be used outside of the function.

Comment: @Crt , did you manage to use the array outside the function? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would help anyone, I was trying this in angular 11.
Since `onload` happens asynchronously. we need to use observable to return the final object which is being processed in the `reader.onload` block.

```
calledFunction(event){
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    return New Observable((subscriber: any)=>{
        reader.onload = function(event) {
          var arrayBuffer = event.target.result;
          var myArray = arrayBuffer.slice(0);
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arrayBuffer.byteLength;
    
          subscriber.next(myArray) // myArray object will be returned to the calling function
          subscriber.complete(); // Complete the subscriber
        }
    })
}
```

now you can call this function anywhere you want as service or function call

```
calledService.calledFunction(event).subscrib(result=>{
    console.log(result)
    // To do your logic based on the result object
})
```